# Converting my iTunes library to romaji

Tags: windows-8, itunes, automation, character-encoding, japanese

I have just added to my iTunes library a bunch of new Japanese songs. When I say a bunch, I mean it. A lot of them. And their titles are mostly in their original Japanese form, which is in kanji, hiragana and katakana.

I'm only just starting to learn the language, which means I can't read most of that. And even if I could, for the sake of things following a sort of standard with the tons of other songs I have in romaji in my library, it would make sense for everything to be the same way.

The last time I added songs - and there were far less than this - it took me a very long while to transliterate everything. So I would like to know if there is a way to speed this up.

**Is there a way to convert my iTunes library from Japanese script to romaji (alphabet) automatically or semi-automatically?** Will it rename folders and files in my iTunes Media folder?

Or is there, at least, a way to make this faster than using a dictionary for every word (and sometimes get mistaken on what's a word, what's two words and what's a modified version of a word that won't be found in a dictionary?

By the way, I'm running Windows (8, Pro, 64 bits).

Comment: I'm coding up a solution after discussing with @Ariane on Root Access.

Comment: @allquixotic Hey, did you ever write that tool? Regards, Majiri

Answer (score 0):

This free software does what you expect, but you need to drag a file one by one.
http://eigoukaiki.s101.xrea.com/software/ganmigi/

And you need to know how to read Japanese or use your imagination to operate this. This would transform all the Japanese word into its phonic alphabets in Romaji style or half-width Katakana, both 1 byte letters

Comment: I'll make sure to give this a try!